# Which is best for android automation calabash or UIAutomator api

Tags: android, testing, functional-testing, ui-automation

Friends please suggest me which is best for android automation - calabash or UIAutomatorViewer. I dont have any idea about calabash, but few of my friends started working on it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the creator of calabash-android so take this with a grain of salt ;-)

UIAutomatorViewer only works on api level 16 and above which means you can't run your test on older phones and tablets. Calabash works on api level 8 and above.

Calabash is unlike UIAutomatorViewer running on your computer driving a server on the device that will interact with your app. That lets you call out to web services and so on. (You could do that on the device as well but you have much more powerful tools available on your computer.)

If you have other questions let me know :)

Comment: thanks... ill try with calabash....

Comment: I just tried uiautomator and it wouldn't connect to my device running Gingerbread. Guess I'll try out calabash. Thanks !